# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'name');

Tags: javascript, discord, roblox

Error:

> Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'name')

Code:

```js
function loop(){
    request.get({
        url: 'https://games.roblox.com/v1/games?universeIds=3652651589',
        rejectUnauthorized: false,
        headers: {
          'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/72.0.3750.0 Iron Safari/537.36'
        }
      }, (err, res, body) => {
        console.log(body.data.name)
      });

    setTimeout(loop, 5000);
}

loop();
```

What must I do?

Comment: Sounds like name isnt on body.data. Try printing just body.data, to determine how to get what you want.

Comment: output: undefined

Comment: It means that body.data doesn't have property named "name", try to log "body" and "body.name" to debug

Comment: when i use just 'body' this time it gives all the data but I want to use only certain data like 'playing'

Comment: still undefined :/

Comment: The `data` property in the JSON that is returned by that endpoint, is an array. An array doesn't have a `name` property. You will have to loop over the elements in `.data`. See [How can I access and process nested objects, arrays or JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/how-can-i-access-and-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json)

Comment: since you keep getting undefined, log the error in your callback, theres might be an error in the req then.

instead of calling setTimeout in loop, why not use setInterval from outside of it

Answer (score 1):

`data` is an **array**, you can not do things like that `data.name`
You need to use some array methods to access the information in the `data` or simply to specify exact index in the array in this case is `0` because the `data` array has only one item in it, but this is kind of not scalable...

`body.data.map((currentElement) => { console.log(currentElement.name) }`
and "On Development" should be printed.

Comment: typeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')

Comment: body.data.map((currentElement) => { console.log(currentElement.name) }

Answer (score -3):

Replace `body.data.name` with `res.data.name`

Comment: same error.

thats the body data ```{"data":[{"id":3652651589,"rootPlaceId":9890477108,"name":"On Development","description":"","sourceName":"On Development","sourceDescription":"","creator":{"id":13708790,"name":"Schrater Studios","type":"Group","isRNVAccount":false},"price":null,"allowedGearGenres":["All"],"allowedGearCategories":[],"isGenreEnforced":true,"copyingAllowed":false,"playing":0,"visits":15,"maxPlayers":6,"created":"2022-06-12T13:56:48.163Z","updated":"2022-06-22T12:27:40.9492273Z","studioAccessToApisAllowed":false,"createVipServersAllowed":false,....}]}```